# How to validate username as email or mobile number in laravel validator?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a field `username`, which can take either `email` or `number` with 10 digit for mobile number

```
'username' => 'required|email'
```

what rule should I write to validate like this ?

or I can say how to merge below two rules

```
'username' => 'required|email'
'username' => 'required|integer|size:10'
```

Comment: I would personally make a custom validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this one :

$username=Input::get('username');
 if(is_numeric($username)){
    $validator=Validator::make(Input::all(),array(
                'username' => 'required|integer|size:10'
            ));
 }else{
 $validator=Validator::make(Input::all(),array(
               'username' => 'required|email'
            ));
}
```

Comment: Make a custom validation for `username` would be better.